# Choose between a and the article in a question without context

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Why we say

> How to cross **the** road?

meanwhile, we also say

> How to read **a** book?

As far as I know, we use "the" when there's some context. For example, I have a car, and I want to paint it, then I say "I want to paint **the** car". But without context about which car I want to paint, I say "How to paint **a** car?"

Could you explain why we use **the** in some sentences instead of **a**?

Comment: _Cross the road_ is a fixed expression, whether or not we know which road is being referred to. You just have to learn that 'that's how we say it'.

Comment: Be aware that "How to paint a car?" is not an interrogative statement with a finite verb. Outside newspaper headlines and refrigerator reminders, you should normally say something like "How do you paint a car? How do I paint a car? How does one paint a car? How can I paint the car? How should I paint the car? How will  you paint the car?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(A)** These are "conventions" used by various communities , where common usage makes it acceptable , even though it is inconsistent (or even wrong , according to other communities) , becoming idiomatic over time.

In you Case , there is some **Ambiguity**.

> How to cross the road?

**(A1)** I would use this when there is a specific road which I want to cross , but it has Dividers. Hence I may ask the a Passser-by "How to cross the [this] road?" who may reply that there is a subway or there is a bridge or there are Divider openings every kilometer , where the reply will be specific to this road.

**(A2)** When using this to refer to all general roads sounds odd , but is acceptable in some communities. When asking this , the reply should ideally be about all roads in general.

This usage occurs when we are talking about either all roads (Eg [rule of the road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_the_road) or [rules of the road](https://www.britannica.com/topic/rules-of-the-road)) or about some hypothetical Idealized road (Eg [one for the road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_for_My_Baby_(and_One_More_for_the_Road)) , [one for the road](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-for-the-road) , [rules of the road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_the_Road_(Anita_O%27Day_album)) or [hit the road jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_the_Road_Jack)).

There may be no Idealized or Hypothetical book , hence it is generally "a book" , not "the book".
When there is indeed such a book (eg in religious contexts or constitutional books or law books or a compendium) then we may use "the book" when talking in that context.

**(B)** It is easy to avoid that by using **Plurals** which is correct in every community or other contexts.

> How to cross roads?
> How to read books?

Usage trends via google ngrams :

[image: roads]

[image: books]